# Angular:- not displaying and hide error message

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Below is the code which is working fine for onclick of submit button, if its error then it will show error on submit button only and once user fill correct information its keep coming up and go only on click of submit button i.e if condition is working for submit button only not for form itself. I guess I am skipping something

Below is HTML file

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pb-3 zip-wrapper">
              <label for="mailingZip" class="required">Zip Code</label>
              <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="mailingZip" [maxLength]="20" [disabled]="setAsResidential" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" [(ngModel)]="mailingAddress.zip.value"
                  autocomplete="off" (keyup)="validateMailingZipCode()" (blur)="validateMailingZipCode()">
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <p *ngIf="mailingAddress.zip.error" class="clearfix error-message">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{mailingAddress.zip.errorMessage}}</p>
            </div>
```

Below is ts file

```
 validateMailingZipCode() {
    let hasErrors: boolean = false;
    if (parseInt(this.mailingAddress.zip.value) >= parseInt('01001') && this.mailingAddress.zip.value.length === 5) {
      return false;
    } else {
      hasErrors = true;
      this.mailingAddress.zip.error = true;
      this.mailingAddress.zip.errorMessage = 'Invalid Zip Code Provided';
    }
    return hasErrors;
  }
```

Comment: You code doesn't have submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset `this.mailingAddress.zip.error` in your function:

```
validateMailingZipCode() {
  this.mailingAddress.zip.error = false; // Reset to false on keyup
  let hasErrors: boolean = false;
  if (parseInt(this.mailingAddress.zip.value) >= parseInt('01001') && this.mailingAddress.zip.value.length === 5) {
    return false;
  } else {
    hasErrors = true;
    this.mailingAddress.zip.error = true;
    this.mailingAddress.zip.errorMessage = 'Invalid Zip Code Provided';
  }
  return hasErrors;
}
```

Comment: Same function for another input causing me same issue. Instead of asking another question here, may I know what should i check to see why keyup event is not showing results

Comment: @Developer `console.log()` the variable at start and at end of your function